# Is it possible to list all the expressions from DataBinder.Eval()?

Tags: c#, data-binding, repeater

I have a Repeater that is databound to a SQL database. To access the information I do the following:

```
string Author = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Author");
```

There are other properties (expressions? as intellisense puts it) that I need to access, but I am unsure of what their names are. Can I loop through the `e.Item.DataItem` and get the names of all the expressions?

I posed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131424/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-property-names-from-a-databound-item) already, sort of, but I think I was unclear. The result of that post gave me what looks like the table structure from the database, not the actual expression names/values:

```
UrlWithExtension [System.String]
ThumbnailUrl [System.String]
Content [System.Object]
Language [System.String]
// etc
```

Getting the values is not really important, just the names of the expressions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be referring to what is called Fields (essentially variables that are declared at class level and made public). You can use the same method that I supplied in that other Q&A thread, with a small modification:

```
obj.GetType().
    GetFields().
    ToList().
    ForEach(p =>
        Console.WriteLine("{0} [{1}]", p.Name, p.FieldType.ToString()
        ));
```

I didn't really think about that when I made the code for the properties, since I almost never expose fields publicly in my classes.

When I need to know what the interface of an object looks like, I often find it easiest to simply add a break point in the debugger, and add a watch to examine the object a bit closer. That will reveal all (non-method) members and their types (and current content as well).

Comment: Unfortunately that is not it. When I run that, I get a blank string (I modified your code slightly to append the text to a string builder instead of outputting to the console. Thanks for your continued input!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your other post appears to be the answer to this one as well.  To get the "Expresions" that you're looking for, you could do something like this...

```
var props = e.Item.DataItem.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (var item in props)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}", item.Name, DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, item.Name)));
}
```

This loop will go over your DataItem and grab each property and output its Name and Value to the console.  If your Author isn't showing up in the list of results, it could be that it isn't a property but a public Field instead, so you should take a look at GetFields() or some of the other methods as well.

Example using GetFields...

```
var props = e.Item.DataItem.GetType().GetFields();

foreach (var item in props)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}", item.Name, DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, item.Name)));
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it must be something else. This gives me the same result as Fredrik's code, just the actual values (ie: UrlWithExtension:~/Libraries/Activation_Key/Activation_Key.sflb.ashx) instead of the type :(.

Comment: Did you try it with GetFields() instead of GetProperties()?

Comment: Yes, that returns a blank string.

Comment: If you're binding to a SQL database, the expressions that you can use with the Eval method will map directly to the columns returned by your query.

Comment: Hmm, well that still doesn't make much sense to me unless the expressions have aliases or something since 'Author' is not in the GetProperties() list. Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure - what does your SQL statement look like that you are binding to?

Comment: Haha, good question. I am utilizing a CMS (telerik's SiteFinity), so I do not have direct access to the data layer to see this. This makes it all the more tricky/annoying.